# Можно ли сделать возврат на активити с передачей данных при нажатии на кнопку "назад" на actionBar?

Tags: android, actionbar

У меня в приложении есть стрелочка назад на actionBar которая делает возврат на предыдущее активити. Подключил я эту кнопку так:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

не спорю что наверное не очень правильно и красиво, но вроде работает. И теперь у меня возник вопрос, можно ли как-то сделать возврат на предыдущий экран по аналогии с intent чтобы например передать на предыдущий экран какие-то параметры.

Comment: слушатель на тулбар повесьте setNavigationOnClickListener

Comment: у меня такого метода не видит) у меня в доступе три метода и все, я пробовал найти тот метод что вы говорите, но его не видит

Comment: а ну да, этот метод привязывается к тулбару

Comment: @Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp()

Comment: у меня получается достать только два метода onCreateSupportNavigateUpTaskStack и onPrepare, того что вы сказали нету

Comment: Вроде actionBar устарел давно и обьявлен deprecated?

Comment: onSupportNavigateUp можно использовать только если от ActionBarActivity вроде как

Comment: речь идет о actionBar или все таки о тулбаре? Если о экшнБаре , то поймать нажатие кнопки Home можно также в onOptionsItemSelected. Она имеет id = android.R.id.home.  адальше все как обычно

Answer (score 2):

Для того, что бы получить результат работы activity, для старта нужно использовать метод startActivityForResult():

```
val intent = Intent(this, TargetActivity::class.java)
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

В activity, результаты которого нужно получить, можно обработать нажатие на back button и вернуть результаты, переопределив метод onOptionsItemSelected() следующим образом:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?) : Boolean {
    return when(item?.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
             val intent = Intent()
             intent.putExtra(... // запихиваете нужные результаты
             setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
             super.onBackPressed()
             true
        }
    ...
```

И получаете результаты в activity в которое возвращаетесь

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data:Intent?){
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        //Здесь получаете данные из intent
    }
}
```

Comment: в твоем примере не закроется активити по нажатию кнопки home

Comment: исправил ответ, спасибо.

Comment: @АлександрКарачёв, у меня появилось почему-то впечатление что ваш вариант для kotlin, или мне кажется?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko вариант для андроид, написан на kotlin. А что не так с котлином? Если вам нужна именно Java, то ставьте тег java к вопросу. А вообще логика та же, методы и аргументы одинаковые, что на джаве, что на котлине.

Comment: @АлександрКарачёв, я понял, сейчас попробую ваш способ перекинуть на java, потому-что вообще я не котлинист и могут быть некоторые сложности)